# Removing parent view

Tags: objective-c

I have on the `storyBoard` `viewA`, that has its `viewControllerA` , than some button in this view make transition(modal)to the next `viewB`- that has `viewControllerB` , than from `B` I go to `C` also with modal transition .(i made a transition by dragging line from a button in a view to another view in storyboard)

When I done with `C`, I want to go back to `A` .

so I can dismiss `C` with :

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

that takes me back to `B` , but I need to go to `A`

1. I tried to pass the view controller from `B` to `C` ,than also dismiss `B` inside `C` -did not worked
2. should I just drag a line in the storyboard from `C` back to `A`  ?
3. when going from `B` to `C`, is there a way in `storyboard`, to also dismiss `B` ?

what is the right way to do so ?

Comment: Seems there is no such functions. You can, however, set a boolean value to your ViewControllerB to tell him to pop if necessary.

Comment: Of course there is a function/way to go back from C to A , my question was how to do that ..

Comment: Dragging a line in storyboard from C to A does work. question is, if that is the right way .. (whats happen to B ?)

Comment: Well, dismiss only pop one level up. Dragging a line from C to A means present again from C to A. It can work, only depends on your situation. What I meant was, before you pop to Controller B, set a boolean like "PopAgain" as true, so B will pop again once it is shown. I am working an example for you.

Comment: Look up "unwind segue"

Answer (score 0):

Try this code is work for me. May it work for you too :)

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Note use **parentViewController** for privious iOS version and above code for iOS5.

```
[self.parentViewController.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is a working example for you.

in ControllerB, you add a property

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL dismissWhenAppear;
```

and add viewDidAppear function

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if (self.dismissWhenAppear) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    }
}
```

in ControllerC, you have

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)button {
    if (([self.presentingViewController isKindOfClass:[TestViewController1 class]])) {
        ((TestViewController1 *)self.presentingViewController).dismissWhenAppear = YES;
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    }];
}
```